# When copying null characters into string, null still gets printed out as garbage

Tags: c, string, pointers, null

I am writing this function that copies n characters from s2 into s1. If s2's length is shorter than n, the rest of the n characters will be made up of null characters.

```
main()
{
    char sourceStr[10];
    char destStr[80];
    int myInt;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(sourceStr);

    printf("Enter the number of characters: ");
    scanf("%d", &myInt);

    printf("Returned string: %s ", copyastring(destStr, sourceStr, myInt));
    return 0;

}

char *copyastring(char * s1, char * s2, int n)
{

    int a = n;
    for( n ; n > 0 ; n--)
    {
            // if end of s2 is reached, the rest of s1 becomes null
        if(*s2 == '\0')
        {
            while(n > 0)
            {
                *s1 = '\0';
                s1++;
                n--;
            }
            break;
        }
            //if-not, copy current s2 value into s1
            //increment both pointers
        else
        {
            *s1 = *s2;
            s2++;
            s1++;
        }
    }
    // Just incase s2 is longer than n, append a null character
    s1++;
*s1 = '\0';
s1--;

    //Reset s1's pointer back to front of s1
    s1 = s1 - a;
    return s1;
}
```

After running this code, and printing out the string returned by the function, i realise all the null characters are printed as garbage characters (unreadable). Why is that so? Doesnt null character terminate the string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you print the string returned by the function?

Comment: How are the strings declared and how are you calling the function ?

Comment: Are you sure `s1` is allocated to a large enough size? And unrelated to the problem, but what do you think `( n ;` does in the `for` statement?

Comment: @MrLister: I think it's harmless but also meaningless.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to save a pointer to `s1` and just return that, instead of doing `s1 - a`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, but I still want to hear what the OP tries to achieve with it.

Comment: probably just "I need three things in my for-statement, so I'll put 'n' here..."

Comment: Ok yeah i always have the nasty habit of having that inital variable in the for statement.

Comment: You should probably step through the code in a debugger, line by line, while examining all variables. Stackoverflow is a great resource, but it shouldn't be used a replacement for a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `s2` is longer than `n` characters then you don't add the terminator to the string `s1`, so printing the returned pointer as a string will produce garbage.

Comment: Ok yes. Now ive edited the code and i still see a single garbabe character at the end.

Comment: @user1234897 You don't have to do that last increase of `s1`, it's already done in the `else` statement in the loop. That will actually put the terminator one beyond the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to `copyastring` where `myInt < strlen(sourceStr)` will fail to add a null terminator tp `destStr`.  You'll then print whatever data appears in the rest of `destStr` plus the stack that follows it, terminating only when your program crashes or comes across a zero byte.

One easy fix for this would be to always add a null terminator at the end of `copyastring`

```
s1 = s1 - a;
s1[n-1] = '\0';
return s1;
```

Comment: isn't this better suited for a comment?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Possibly although its the only obvious flaw I can see in the code so I'm guessing that this is the answer

Comment: If there isn't enough information to find the answer, then the question can't be answered, simple as that.

Comment: There is enough information to spot an obvious flaw in the code.  As Joachim has also just done.  It doesn't seem that uncommon to use answers to report obvious flaws that may well address a question.

Comment: From the FAQ: " Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: -  commentary on the question or other answers, - asking another, different question"

Comment: Thanks. I guess this comes down to me claiming that my post provides the best possible answer to the question in its current form. If the consensus is that we should refuse to provide an answer until a question is improved to the point that any answer is unarguably correct or wrong, I'll happily delete my answer

Comment: Hmm just asked for help. I hope to not spark any arguments among any of you.
Anyway added my main function to the code. Sorry for not adding it just now as i didnt want a code to be too long to read.